# Unity 2d animation won't play from script

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm making a 2D sidescrolling game in Unity, and when the player shoots an obstacle, I want the obstacle animation to play and then destroy itself. I got it to destroy itself, but the animation won't play. Any suggestions?

```
protected Animation obsanim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    obsanim = GetComponent<Animation> ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "circle") 
    {
        obsanim.Play ("circobs");
        Destroy (gameObject, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me, assuming of course that the animation doesn't last more than 1 second. You could use `animation["circobs"].length` to figure out when you need to destroy.

Maybe the animation you're playing is in a lower layer than the current one?